# Export map keyboard shortcut?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, shortcuts

I'm running ArcMap 10.3 and am wondering the quickest way to export a map from the layout view without navigating up to the File menu & clicking the "Export Map" feature. Which is to say, I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for this feature.

I can't find a built-in keyboard shortcut for exporting but I've noticed that if the File drop down menu is clicked, I can simply hit the <kbd>E</kbd> key and that will bring up the Export Map dialog box. Does anyone know of a shortcut to at least open/expose the File drop down menu in the top left? If so, then it's a quick 2 strokes and I'm there.

Comment: you can create a toolbar with a shortcut (like using CTRL+ALT+E) http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/adding-a-command-to-a-context-menu.htm

Comment: Thanks! This got me part of the way there - found out I can just assign the _Export Map_ function a custom keyboard shortcut of my own under the "Keyboard" option of the Customize dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a shortcut to at least open/expose the File drop
>   down menu in the top left? If so, then it's a quick 2 strokes and I'm
>   there.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the [standard Windows keyboard shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#General_shortcuts) to open the File Menu, so <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> will get you your Export dialog.